# How to create a .net chart object with a series based on a data subset?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2010

I'm working in VS2010 on a visual basic application.  It takes in serial port data, writes it to an access database, and then graphs the data.  The data only comes in once every minute, so it's not like I'm building an oscilloscope.  Right now, the chart is reading from the database using a table adapter and graphing just fine, so long as I keep the number of records in the database low.

The Problem:
If I add too many records to the database, the chart shows a red "X" through it.  I've played with changing the axes, but it is still a problem.  I don't really need to graph the whole database.  The twenty most recent records would suffice.

How can I make a chart series with only a small subset of the database in it.  Perhaps it cold be populated with a query?  I'm very new to databases in general, so maybe this is an easy one.

Thanks,
Casbar

Answer (score 1):

You need to return only the latest 20 records each minute, so for example use a timer control and in its tick event fetch the last 20 records inserted into the database.

In Microsoft Access, create a query to confirm the results you should get back in the .Net app. Here is the SQL query run in MS Access:

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM tblData ORDER BY DateCreated
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM tblData ORDER BY tblID DESC
```

Now in your .net app you need to use the following NameSpace:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

Then read the last 20 values in from the Access Database:

```
Private Xvalues as New List(Of Integer)
Private Yvalues as New List(Of Integer)

Private Sub GetData()

Dim con As OleDbConnection
Dim sql As String 
str = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.oledb.4.0;Data Source=C:\yourAccessDB.mdb;"
con = New OleDbConnection(str)       
sql = "SELECT TOP 20 * FROM tblData ORDER BY DateCreated"
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand  
Dim r As OleDbDataReader  
Try  
   con.Open() 
   cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)  
   r = cmd.ExecuteReader() 
   While dr.Read() 
     XValues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(r("chartX")))
     YValues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(r("chartY")))
   End While   
   r.Close()      
   con.Close()    
Catch ex As OleDbException 
     MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, “Oledb Error”)   
Catch ex As Exception   
     MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, “General Error”)
End Try   
End Sub
```

Then hook the GetData() method above and your charting function to be called in the Timers Tick Event. I imagine your going to need to delete/archive old records and clear out X & Yvalue variables too.
*Please note not tested.*